# Making backup of microsoft mail without outlook scenario, advise

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, email, microsoft-outlook

I would like to save my mails from Microsoft.
I have read that the only way is to download outlook. 
Online service is not supporting backups.

But I don't want to have outlook at my system.
So I have figured out to use VirtualBox for this issue. 
For this I have downloaded Windows XP SP3 image and I am thinking to create virtual disk for this. 
At this moment I have realized that Windows XP and old outlook may be bugged so this is not the best way.

So I could virtualize Windows 7. And then.. I have thought that maybe instead of virtualizing by VirtualBox from Cisco, maybe I can create Windows 7 or XP as live USB.

Which one from this proposal would be best in effort and safety / privacy ?

Maybe someone have fix my problem in different way, if yes, please share with me the idea. How to make backup of my mails from Microsoft account (not personal, from University) without installing outlook on my personal system.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cisco has nothing to do with VirtualBox.  Wouldn't it be easier to just use Thunderbird or some other email client if you don't like Outlook?

Comment: This is quite satisfing proposal.
However if possible I would prefer not contain any additional program on my system. I am so minimalistic. If I don't need it (except make this backup once for month or three) I would prefer to keep my system most clean. 
Anyway thank you, this is better way than outlook !

Comment: My mistake, I have check, VirtualBox is from Oracle. Thank you for correcting me ! Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Outlook.com supports IMAP. You can use thunderbird to get a local copy of your mails.

- Server: imap-mail.outlook.com
- Port: 993
- You'll have to enable SSL

Source: https://blogs.office.com/2013/09/12/outlook-com-now-has-imap/

Comment: This is quite satisfing proposal. However if possible I would prefer not contain any additional program on my system. I am so minimalistic. If I don't need it (except make this backup once for month or three) I would prefer to keep my system most clean.
Anyway thank you, this is better way than outlook !

Comment: There are portable versions of Thunderbird that don't require installation.